# Why does the C++ standard keep such a redundant function?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, standards

1. [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)'s prototype:

   ```
   size_type find( CharT ch, size_type pos = 0 ) const;
   ```
2. [std::string::find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)'s prototype:

   ```
   std::size_type find_first_of( CharT ch, size_type pos = 0 ) const;
   ```

Both have the same function. But it's obvious that the latter is redundant.

I think this redundancy would make the user confused, because `find_first_of` means "find anyone of the given characters", rather than "find the given character".

Why does the C++ standard keep such a redundant function?

Comment: For consistent, I guess. E.g. all `find` has a corresponding `find_first_of`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a **subtle** difference between them. Bjarne clarifies their usage as:

> The `find_∗_of()` functions differ from `find()` and `rfind()` by looking for a *single* character, rather than a *whole sequence* of characters.
>
> ```
> string s {"accdcde"};
> auto i1 = s.find("cd");           // i1==2 s[2]=='c' && s[3]=='d'
> auto i2 = s.rfind("cd");          // i2==4 s[4]=='c' && s[5]=='d'
> auto i3 = s.find_first_of("cd");  // i3==1 s[1]=='c'
> auto i4 = s.find_last_of("cd");   // i4==5 s[5]=='d'
> ```

**Edit:**

As rightly observed by @juanchopanza, this clarification doesn't exactly relates to the overloaded version (taking `char`) presented by OP.

> **Is there any rationale behind?**

IMO, `find_first_of( char, pos)` could have come up as a case of providing  consistency over its *counterpart's signature* `find_last_of( char, pos)`, which has a reverse functionality compared to `find(char, pos)` which goes from left to right.

Note that `find(char, pos)` can supplant `find_first_of( char, pos)` but not `find_last_of( char, pos)`. Absence of `find_first_of( char, pos)` could possibly lead to some confusion in developers, so it's better to have this overloaded version as well.

Comment: You're not using either of the overloads in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a member of the standardisation committee, but it isn't hard to reason about why.

`find()` and `find_first_of()` are both families of functions.

`find()` finds substrings.  `find_first_of()` finds the first character in the first argument that matches.  When only a single character is specified, in both cases, they do the same thing.

Typically, if using such functions to parse strings, a developer will use a number of overloads of `find()` (searching for substrings) OR a number of overloads of `find_first_of()` (searching for a single character that meets some criterion), rather than using a mix of both, and rely on consistency of logic between the various functions being used.

While it is possible to mix the two (logically), forcing a developer who is otherwise using `find_first_of()` to use `find()`, or vice versa, makes the code a little harder to reason about, therefore harder to get right, harder to maintain.

The effort of specifying such functions (in the standard, the effort of developing such functions (once, per implementation) is significantly less than the effort of many developers having to think harder about what functions they USE, and therefore have to work harder to get their programs working right, and then to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) don't do the same function.

For [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

> Finds the first substring equal to the given character sequence. Search begins at pos, i.e. the found substring must not begin in a position preceding pos.

For [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of):

> Finds the first character equal to one of the characters in the given character sequence. The search considers only the interval [pos, size()).

For only the case of the set is single character, parameter is `CharT`, those two functions are coincidence duplicated.